# Problem with trying to define a Gobject boilerplate

Tags: c, glib, gobject

I was trying to create a new class but the error occurs

```
error: ‘OnvifFactory’ was not declared in this scope
G_DEFINE_TYPE (OnvifFactory, onvif_factory, GST_TYPE_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY);
```

This is my code.

```
struct _OnvifFactory
{
  GstRTSPEOnvifMediaFactory parent;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (OnvifFactory, onvif_factory, GST_TYPE_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY);

static void
onvif_factory_class_init (OnvifFactoryClass * klass)
{
  GstRTSPMediaFactoryClass *mf_class = GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY_CLASS (klass);
}

static void
onvif_factory_init (OnvifFactory * factory)
{
}

static GstRTSPMediaFactory *
onvif_factory_new (void)
{
  GstRTSPMediaFactory *result;

  result =
      GST_RTSP_MEDIA_FACTORY (g_object_new (onvif_factory_get_type (), NULL));

  return result;
}
```

Was trying to create an empty template from which I could slowly populate with more functions. However it seem my template was also in error

Regards

Comment: Can you also put in the code from your header file? Usually it has something like `G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE()` in it, which actually declares the struct

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `typedef struct _OnvifFactory OnvifFactory;` above your struct definition.